# Pandas groupby column and average corresponding rows with each other

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have a pandas dataframe with the following structure.

```
Row Column  Run Depth   Signal
0   0   0   0   4
0   0   0   1   3
0   0   0   2   5
0   0   0   3   3
0   0   0   4   4
0   1   0   0   6
0   1   0   1   7
0   1   0   2   4
0   1   0   3   2
0   1   0   4   1
1   1   0   0   1
1   1   0   1   4
1   1   0   2   3
1   1   0   3   2
1   1   0   4   1
0   0   1   0   5
0   0   1   1   7
0   0   1   2   1
0   0   1   3   1
0   0   1   4   1
0   1   1   0   3
0   1   1   1   4
0   1   1   2   2
0   1   1   3   1
0   1   1   4   3
1   1   1   0   3
1   1   1   1   3
1   1   1   2   4
1   1   1   3   4
1   1   1   4   5
0   0   2   0   5
0   0   2   1   5
0   0   2   2   4
0   0   2   3   1
0   0   2   4   3
0   1   2   0   1
0   1   2   1   3
0   1   2   2   5
0   1   2   3   4
0   1   2   4   6
1   1   2   0   7
1   1   2   1   2
1   1   2   2   1
1   1   2   3   2
1   1   2   4   3
```

I would like average the 'Signal' by the 'Run', such that e.g., the 'Signal' from Row=0, Column=0, Run=0, Depth=2 is averaged with Row=0, Column=0, Run=1, Depth=2 and Row=0, Column=0, Run=2, Depth=2.

In the end, the averaged dataframe would look like the following with the numbers from above.

```
Row Column  Depth   Signal
0   0   0   4.667
0   0   1   5.000
0   0   2   3.333
0   0   3   1.667
0   0   4   2.667
0   1   0   3.333
0   1   1   4.667
0   1   2   3.667
0   1   3   2.333
0   1   4   3.333
1   1   0   3.667
1   1   1   3
1   1   2   2.667
1   1   3   2.667
1   1   4   3
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: `df.groupby(['Row','Column','Depth'], as_index=False)['Signal'].mean()`

Comment: Thank you so much! This works like a charm.

Comment: @Chris might as well put that as an answer